# Raphael animation for multiple divs

Tags: jquery, raphael

I newbie to Raphael and i wanted raphael animation for multiple div. Currently i have animation for single div. But i am unable to do for multiple div it get conflicts.

The following is code

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/04/22/animated-skills-diagram/

HTML

```
<div class="diagram"></div>
        <div class="get">
        <div class="arc">
                <span class="text">JavaScript</span>
                <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="95" />
                <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#97BE0D" />
        </div>
            <div class="arc">
                <span class="text">CSS3</span>
                <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="90" />
                <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#D84F5F" />
            </div>
       </div>

<div class="diagram"></div>
        <div class="get">
        <div class="arc">
                <span class="text">JavaScript</span>
                <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="95" />
                <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#97BE0D" />
        </div>
            <div class="arc">
                <span class="text">CSS3</span>
                <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="90" />
                <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#D84F5F" />
            </div>
       </div>
```

so on...

JAVASCRIPT

```
var o = {
    init: function(){
        this.diagram();

    },
    random: function(l, u){
        return Math.floor((Math.random()*(u-l+1))+l);
    },
    diagram: function(){
        var r = Raphael($('.diagram'),600,600),  //need effects for all the div
            rad =  3,
            defaultText = 'Skills',
            speed = 250;

        r.circle(300, 300, 20).attr({ stroke: 'none', fill: '#193340' });

        var title = r.text(300, 300, defaultText).attr({
            font: '12px Arial',
            fill: '#fff'
        }).toFront();

        r.customAttributes.arc = function(value, color, rad){
            var v = 3.6*value,
                alpha = v == 360 ? 359.99 : v,
                random = o.random(91, 240),
                a = (random-alpha) * Math.PI/180,
                b = random * Math.PI/180,
                sx = 300 + rad * Math.cos(b),
                sy = 300 - rad * Math.sin(b),
                x = 300 + rad * Math.cos(a),
                y = 300 - rad * Math.sin(a),
                path = [['M', sx, sy], ['A', rad, rad, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]];
            return { path: path, stroke: color }
        }

        $('.get').find('.arc').each(function(i){
            var t = $(this), 
                color = t.find('.color').val(),
                value = t.find('.percent').val(),
                text = t.find('.text').text();

            rad += 17;  
            var z = r.path().attr({ arc: [value, color, rad], 'stroke-width': 12 });

            z.mouseover(function(){
                this.animate({ 'stroke-width': 20, opacity: .75 }, 1000, 'elastic');
                if(Raphael.type != 'VML') //solves IE problem
                this.toFront();
                title.stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, speed, '>', function(){
                    this.attr({ text: text + '\n' + value + '%' }).animate({ opacity: 1 }, speed, '<');
                });
            }).mouseout(function(){
                this.stop().animate({ 'stroke-width': 12, opacity: 1 }, speed*4, 'elastic');
                title.stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, speed, '>', function(){
                    title.attr({ text: defaultText }).animate({ opacity: 1 }, speed, '<');
                }); 
            });
        });

    }
}
$(function(){ o.init(); });
```

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/04/22/animated-skills-diagram/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been a while since I've used this so correct me if I'm wrong, but:

```
var r = Raphael($('.diagram'),600,600),  //need effects for all the div
            rad =  3,
            defaultText = 'Skills',
            speed = 250;
```

The Raphael object creates a canvas and then you manipulate it, here you have multiple divs. Is the problem that Raphael is expecting a single element (why the author used id instead of styleclass) and the issue that your returning an array of elements?

If this is the issue try getting all of the divs first and then execute this code for each div, not passing all the divs into this function.

Comment: i am using arraylist and generating multiple div and how do i execute this code for each div. Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look as though you using an arrayList. the code i quoted above is used and then in mulitple places you just reference r.circle etc. whereas later code like " $('.get').find('.arc').each( " is being used (each means it would go through each one). Why not simply take his code excatly, give each div a unique id like he does, and change o.init to take in a string for the id, pass that into diagram function and call o.init("diagram"); o.init("diagram2"); etc. Would be a lot easier for you if you don't understand this code

Comment: Taking another look at it my last comment won't work as the code uses the other class / id's to find elements, meaning everything would have to be unique. This site is to ask people ideas and small solutions, it is not to ask people to do something for you, I don't have the time to investigate this for you. If you don't understand the technologies then don't use them or put in the time to learn them. You will need to loop around each div with class "diagram" and get each inner div by using something like "div.getElementsByTagName(tagname)" which is a standard dom method. as ...

Comment: searching for "$('.get')" is going to return all the elements with class="get" on the page. This code was designed to be used once on a page, changing its use will require work / studying the code

Comment: Thanks Sir, o.init("diagram"); o.init("diagram2");  code worked. But sir can u please tell me how to give this $('.get').find('.arc').each to particular div.

Comment: again exactly the same issue, change them from all the same class names to unique id's  id="get", id="get2" etc. then simply "$(**getID**).find('.arc').each" (replacing **getID** with the actual id) will work